# How mix Month view and List view in same page with Calendar Base extension in TYPO3 7.6.14

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have been seeing the code of Calendar Base but I have not understood the way as work markers and its functionality in the code.

I want to know if is possible to create a mini calendar and in the moment that I click one day with events show below them the list.

Please guide me what is the way to resolve it, not give me a code.

Comment: I will write my solution http://www.vikingeskibsmuseet.dk/kalender/ but it takes a while

Comment: Please, tell me when the post will be ready

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of possible configurations for EXT:cal.
I will only give the minimum required configurations for EXT:cal version 1.10.3 in TYPO3 CMS 7.6 as I used for one of my projects (not the sliding one, as mentioned i first comment).

You have installed EXT:cal and include static typoscripts (*'Standard CSS-based template'* and maybe *'Standard CSS styles'*).

At your calendar page in TYPO3 you create two contentelements of type plugin, where you choose *'TYPO3 calendar'* as plugin.
The first contentelement for month-mini-view, the second contentelement for list-view, with following configurations:

1. Contentelement plugin month-mini-view:

Tab *'General settings'*
field *'Allowed views'* 
select *'Month'* only.

Tab *'Month view'*
field *'Display as a mini calendar'*
activate checkbox.

2. Contentelement plugin list-view:

Tab *'General settings'*
field *'Allowed views'*
select *'List'* and *'Single Event'* in this order.

All other fields in plugin configuration are empty or has default value. I prefer, to not use field *Record Storage Page*, use typoscript *'plugin.tx_cal_controller.pidList'* instead.

At frontend you should already see a month-mini and a list view.

Add following typoscript configuration (setup) to your page tree, which I found useful when using mont-mini and list view in combination:

```
// General
plugin.tx_cal_controller.pidList = [!!!-FILL_HERE_YOUR_CAL_STORAGE-PIDS-PLEASE-!!!]

// List view
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.starttime = today
// Use getdate and custom start&end date to use link from minical inside listview
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|year >0]
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate = 1
[else]
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate = 0
[global]
// Adapt list view for urls from monthMini view
// year-view: if (yaer=true && month=false && week=false && day=false)
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|year >0] && [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|month <1] && [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|week <1] && [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|day <1]
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomStarttime = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomEndtime = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customStarttimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customEndtimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.starttime = yearstart
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.endtime = yearend
[global]
// month-view: if (month=true && day=false)
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|month >0] && [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|day <1]
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomStarttime = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomEndtime = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customStarttimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customEndtimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.starttime = monthstart
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.endtime = monthend
[global]
// week-view: if (week=true && (weekday=0 OR weekday=1 OR weekday>1)) // weekday>0 doesnt worx at all
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|week >0]
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomEndtime = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.customEndtimeRelativeToGetdate = 1
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.endtime = +1 week
[global]
// day-view: if (day=true && week=false (&& weekday=false))
[globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|day >0] && [globalVar = GP:tx_cal_controller|week <1]
  # hide ' - enddate' in header (startdate - enddate)
  plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.heading.2 >
[global]

// Month view
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.monthMakeMiniCal = 1
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.endPointCorrection = 9024000
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.dayViewLink.prioriCalc >
```

Now you would like to get week-numbers as link to week period or day-numbers as link to this day in the current view.
Since EXT:cal version 1.9 I need to XCLASS the main controller method, to set view-pid for day,week,month,year,list..view.

You will need a sitepackage extension, in the following example EXT:mysitepackage with minimum following files:

- Classes/Xclass/CalController.php
- ext_localconf.php
- ext_emconf.php
- ext_icon.gif

Content for Classes/Xclass/CalController.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Mysitepackage\Xclass;

/**
 * Extended main controller for calendar base
 *
 * @package TYPO3
 * @subpackage tx_mysitepackage
 * @copyright Copyright belongs to the respective authors
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU General Public License, version 3 or later
 */
class CalController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Cal\Controller\Controller {

    /**
     * Override main controller function that serves as the entry point from TYPO3.
     * 
     * @param array The content array
     * @param array The conf array
     * @return string of calendar data
     */
    public function main($content, $conf) {
        /**
         * Use dynamic viewPid for links in month-mini view (day, week, month, year), as used in \TYPO3\CMS\Cal\View\New[VIEW]View->get[VIEW]Link().
         * Fx: Each monthMini view has dayLinks. These links are only enabled, if [VIEW]ViewPid is set (should be set to current page id).
         * TS setup configuration for 'plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.[VIEW].[VIEW]ViewPid' is not stdWrap'able.
         * 
         * See TS:
         * plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.[VIEW].[VIEW]ViewPid = TEXT
         * plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.[VIEW].[VIEW]ViewPid.data = TSFE:id
         * plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.[VIEW].[VIEW]ViewPid.insertData = 1
         */
        // Day
        if ($conf ['view.'] ['day.'] ['dayViewPid.']) {
            $conf ['view.'] ['day.'] ['dayViewPid'] = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf ['view.'] ['day.'] ['dayViewPid'], $conf ['view.'] ['day.'] ['dayViewPid.']);
        }
        // Week
        if ($conf ['view.'] ['week.'] ['weekViewPid.']) {
            $conf ['view.'] ['week.'] ['weekViewPid'] = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf ['view.'] ['week.'] ['weekViewPid'], $conf ['view.'] ['week.'] ['weekViewPid.']);
        }
        // Month
        if ($conf ['view.'] ['month.'] ['monthViewPid.']) {
            $conf ['view.'] ['month.'] ['monthViewPid'] = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf ['view.'] ['month.'] ['monthViewPid'], $conf ['view.'] ['month.'] ['monthViewPid.']);
        }
        // Year
        if ($conf ['view.'] ['year.'] ['yearViewPid.']) {
            $conf ['view.'] ['year.'] ['yearViewPid'] = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($conf ['view.'] ['year.'] ['yearViewPid'], $conf ['view.'] ['year.'] ['yearViewPid.']);
        }
        return parent::main($content, $conf);
    }
}
```

Content for ext_localconf.php

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

// XClass main controller class to adjust $conf. See EXT:mysitepackage/Classes/Xclass/CalController.php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Cal\\Controller\\Controller'] = array(
    'className' => 'Vendorname\\Mysitepackage\\Xclass\\CalController',
);
```

Install and ensure, that Xclass is working. Then you can add following typoscript configuration to existing setup:

```
/**
 * Xclass special
 *
 * Use dynamic viewPid for links in month-mini view (day, week, month, year), as used in \TYPO3\CMS\Cal\View\New[VIEW]View->get[VIEW]Link().
 * Fx: Each monthMini view has dayLinks. These links are only enabled, if [VIEW]ViewPid is set (should be set to current page id).
 * TS setup configuration for 'plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.[VIEW].[VIEW]ViewPid' is not stdWrap'able.
 *
 * XClass main controller class to adjust $conf. See EXT:mysitepackage/Classes/Xclass/CalController.php
 */
# day
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.day.dayViewPid = TEXT
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.day.dayViewPid.data = TSFE:id
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.day.dayViewPid.insertData = 1
# week
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.week.weekViewPid = TEXT
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.week.weekViewPid.data = TSFE:id
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.week.weekViewPid.insertData = 1
# month
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.monthViewPid = TEXT
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.monthViewPid.data = TSFE:id
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.monthViewPid.insertData = 1
# year
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.year.yearViewPid = TEXT
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.year.yearViewPid.data = TSFE:id
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.year.yearViewPid.insertData = 1
```

And all numbers in month-view should be a link, if it contains a valid event day or period.

You will miss a link to next or previous month, which will stay i current month-mini and list view combination.
Then you need to adapt some templates. Have a look at:

*plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.month.monthMiniTemplate*
and markers for *###PREV_MONTHLINK###* and *###NEXT_MONTHLINK###*.

I could describe this in an other question.

Comment: I have been working in this using your guide. I wanna comment you many things about the first typoscript.

Comment: The first condition always is false, so `plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useGetdate` is 0, as a consequence I could not see the events for today. Delete the condition and set the value 1 works. And other conditions are false too. So when I delete all condition the line `plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.useCustomEndtime = 1` in section of `year-view`, so I comented this line. I have the all code but I do not see the links and the new php file controller does not run, I tried `echo`

Comment: Try my test extension, which has been tested and running with EXT:cal version 1.10.3 in TYPO3 CMS 7.6 http://enobe.de/mysitepackage.zip

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I am going to seek why didn´t work before. In the other way I worked with my own site extension including the source, now is a separate extension

Comment: Its fine with your own. Maybe I forgot some detail in my description here or you did in yours

Comment: I can not set the tick in the question, It said I have to increase my reputation, so I will do that and return for give you the tick